# Java Pair<Long,String> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast Exception

Tags: java, jsp

This is Pair.java

```
public class Pair<K, V> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6888452733947143748L;
    private K id;
    private V value;

    public Pair() {

    }

    public Pair(final K id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Pair(final K id, final V value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String value = "";
        if (this.value != null) {
            value = this.value.toString();
        }
        return value;
    }

    public String toStringExtended() {

        String idStr = "null";
        if (id != null) {
            idStr = id.toString();
        }
        String valStr = "null";
        if (value != null) {
            valStr = value.toString();
        }
        return "Pair[" + idStr + ";" + valStr + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = (prime * result) + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = (prime * result) + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Pair<K, V> other = (Pair<K, V>) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value)) {
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }

    public K getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final K id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

I get a list of pairs

```
List<Pair<Long,String>> list = service.findAllLiteByCmp(Company cmp);
```

-- When I pass result list into a jsp file I get the error.

```
<c:forEach items="${compList }" var="entity" >
    "<option value="${entity.id}">${entity.value}</option>              
</c:forEach>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

How I solve the issue ?

Comment: Can you attach code that throws this exception and full stack trace?

Comment: The value of `id` is not working. Check its value. Your code is running on my machine fine when id is long.

Comment: Thansk for all  It was very helpful